# Debugging a Flask app running in Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I've been working on a new dev platform using nginx/gunicorn and Flask for my application.

Ops-wise, everything works fine - the issue I'm having is with debugging the Flask layer. When there's an error in my code, I just get a straight 500 error returned to the browser and nothing shows up on the console or in my logs.

I've tried many different configs/options.. I guess I **must** be missing something obvious.

My gunicorn.conf:

```
import os

bind = '127.0.0.1:8002'
workers = 3
backlog = 2048
worker_class = "sync"
debug = True
proc_name = 'gunicorn.proc'
pidfile = '/tmp/gunicorn.pid'
logfile = '/var/log/gunicorn/debug.log'
loglevel = 'debug'
```

An example of some Flask code that borks- testserver.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template_string
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    n = 1/0
    return "DIV/0 worked!"
```

And finally, the command to run the flask app in gunicorn:

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py testserver:app
```

Thanks y'all

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The Flask config is entirely separate from gunicorn's. Following [the Flask documentation on config files](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#configuring-from-files), a good solution would be change my source to this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
```

And in config.py:

```
DEBUG = True
```

Comment: And of course this makes sense, if we treat gunicorn and Flask as discrete entities. Unlike running Django in gunicorn.

Comment: That's the right answer.  By default Flask runs in production mode where it does not report errors.  For handling errors in production mode you want to have a look at this: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/

Comment: which version ?

gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: -d
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: --debug
$ gunicorn -v
gunicorn (version 19.9.0)

Answer (score 93):

The accepted solution doesn't work for me.

Gunicorn is a pre-forking environment and apparently [the Flask debugger doesn't work in a forking environment](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#debug-mode).

> #### Attention
>
> Even though the interactive debugger does not work in
> forking environments (which makes it nearly impossible to use on
> production servers) [...]

Even if you set `app.debug = True`, you will still only get an empty page with the message *Internal Server Error* if you run with `gunicorn testserver:app`. The best you can do with gunicorn is to run it with `gunicorn --debug testserver:app`. That gives you the trace in addition to the *Internal Server Error* message. However, this is just the same text trace that you see in the terminal and not the Flask debugger.

Adding the `if __name__ ...` section to the testserver.py and running `python testserver.py` to start the server in development gets you the Flask debugger. **In other words, don't use gunicorn in development if you want the Flask debugger.**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

## Tip for Heroku users:
Personally I still like to use `foreman start`, instead of `python testserver.py` since [it sets up all the env variables for me](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-foreman). To get this to work:

#### Contents of `Procfile`

```
web: bin/web
```

#### Contents of `bin/web`, file is relative to project root

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$FLASK_ENV" == "development" ]; then
        python app.py
else
        gunicorn app:app -w 3
fi
```

#### In development, create a `.env` file relative to project root with the following contents (docs [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-foreman))

```
FLASK_ENV=development
DEBUG=True
```

Also, don't forget to change the `app.config['DEBUG']...` line in `testserver.py` to something that won't run Flask in debug mode in production.

```
app.config['DEBUG'] = os.environ.get('DEBUG', False)
```

Comment: Just to note, the original question was actually about getting the stack trace shown *at all*. I don't use the interactive debugger. Nice answer though.

Comment: the .env file in those docs is for heroku envs. If you set the heroku env FLASK_ENV=development then when it ran the procfile live it would execute the first if and run python app.py. with debug still set to True. Or i'm i missing something.

Comment: its worth noting that you have to make the bin/web executable with chmod +x bin/web.

Comment: @nick-zalutskiy the [`--debug` flag has been removed since version `19.3`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.3/news.html#id8), could you update your answer?

Comment: This is such a violation of the dev-prod parity principle it makes me cringe. But so I take there's no alternative to using Werkzeug for local dev if we want to be able to use Flask's debug mode?

Answer (score 24):

**For Heroku users**, there is a simpler solution than creating a bin/web script like suggested by Nick.

Instead of `foreman start`, just use `foreman run python app.py`  if you want to debug your application in development.

Comment: The problem is if you have more than one process it doesn't start e.g. `web: gunicorn server:app
worker: python worker.py`

Comment: +1 This gives the standard debugging output in the browser instead of in just the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I had similiar problem when running flask under gunicorn I didn't see stacktraces in browser (had to look at logs every time). Setting DEBUG, FLASK_DEBUG, or anything mentioned on this page didn't work. Finally I did this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(settings_map[environment])
if environment == 'development':
    from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
    app_runtime = DebuggedApplication(app, evalex=False)
else:
    app_runtime = app
```

Note evalex is disabled because interactive debbugging won't work with forking (gunicorn).

Answer (score 1):

I used this:

```
gunicorn "swagger_server.__main__:app" -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really run it with gunicorn and for example use the flask `reload` option upon code changes.

I've used following snippets in my api launchpoint:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

try:
    if os.environ["yourapp_environment"] == "local":
        run_as_local = True
        # some other local configs e.g. paths
        app.logger.info('Running server in local development mode!')
except KeyError as err:
    if "yourapp_environment" in err.args:
        run_as_local = False
        # some other production configs e.g. paths
        app.logger.info('No "yourapp_environment env" given so app running server in production mode!')
    else:
        raise

...
...
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if run_as_local:
        app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port='8058', debug=True)
    else:
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

For above solution you need to give `export yourapp_environment = "local"` in the console.

now I can run my local as `python api.py` and prod `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8058 api:app`

The `else` statement `app.run()` is not actually needed, but I keep it for reminding me about host, port etc.

Answer (score -3):

Try setting the debug flag on the run command like so

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py --debug testserver:app
```

and keep the `DEBUG = True` in your Flask application. There must be a reason why your debug option is not being applied from the config file but for now the above note should get you going.

Comment: That flag just shows gunicorn level debugging, not actual application code errors.