# Python code working locally but not on server, Internal Server Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, heroku, internal-server-error

This is the Python code that i am using:

```
@app.route("/getInformation", methods=['GET'])           
def domain(): 

    urlList = []

    urlList.append("http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57109")
    urlList.append("http://127.0.0.1/")
    urlList.append("http://gbgfotboll.se/serier/?scr=table&ftid=57108")

    date = '2015-04-18'

    # use this in real mode: currentDate = (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

    homeScore = "0"
    awayScore = "0"
    homeTeam = ""
    awayTeam = ""

    time_xpath = XPath("td[1]/span/span//text()[2]")
    team_xpath = XPath("td[2]/a/text()")
    league_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/h1//text()")

    for url in urlList:
        test = 2
        rows_xpath = XPath("//*[@id='content-primary']/table/tbody/tr[td[1]/span/span//text()='%s']" % (date))
        html = lxml.html.parse(url)

        divName = league_xpath(html)[0]

        trash, divisionName = divName.rsplit("- ")

        dict[divisionName] = {}

        for id,row in enumerate(rows_xpath(html)):
            #time = time_xpath(row)[0].strip()   #use this in real code
            time = "1%d"%test +":00"    # remove this later
            test += 1 #remove this
            test %= 3 # remove this later
            team = team_xpath(row)[0]
            homeTeam, awayTeam = team.split(" - ")

            hour, minute = time.split(":")
            newTime = timeConvert(hour, minute)

            dict[divisionName].update({ id :{"time":str(newTime),"tempTime": time  ,"homeTeam":homeTeam,"homeScore":homeScore, "awayTeam":awayTeam, "awayScore":awayScore, "events" :[] }})

    with open('gameFile.txt', 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(dict, handle)


    return Response(mimetype='application/json') //Is there a better way?
//Note i am not trying to send anything back. i just noticed when running locally not writing this gave me an internal server error
```

When i go to http://localhost:5000/getInformation everything seems ok no error message is being shown and also it is doing what it should do. However when i put it on my server and run it there i receive an error message.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

If it is any help, i am using Heroku to upload the code to the server. I am also using Heroku's built in command **foreman start** to try the code locally.

**EDIT1**

Solved it thanks to the comments below by checking the logs. The error was:

```
IOError: Error reading file 'http://127.0.0.1/': failed to load external entity "http://127.0.0.1/"
```

Then it struck to me its a local address that i was running on my pc. Commenting out

```
urlList.append("http://127.0.0.1/")
```

Worked fine. Thank you

Comment: figure out where the logs are stored and look in the log for the error that occured... or figure out how to run apps in debug mode on heroku

Comment: But can there be anything bad in the code? Since its working locally why not remotly? @JoranBeasley

Comment: of coarse ... not only can there ... there obviously is since you get an error (perhaps you are missing an import or they use a different python on heroku or you are trying to access a path that does not exist ...etc ... it will likely be a very easy fix ... once you figure out what the problem is

Comment: I think you can also do something like `app.debug = True` and get a better traceback (assuming it gets that far) ... add that line right after `app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: [Enabling debug mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950674/debugging-a-flask-app-running-in-gunicorn), logging output to stdout [using `--log-file -`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#adding-gunicorn-to-your-application-procfile) and viewing logs with [`heroku logs`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django#view-the-logs) should work to get to the reason for your 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Thank you found the answer.