# How can I deploy my Flask app with debugger and autoreload?

Tags: python, web, flask, server

I have built a simple Flask app and I want do deploy it on Digital Ocean. I tried gunicorn but debugger and auto reloader no longer works. I was a php developer and I like to save changes and reload to see changes and errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gunicorn do deploy your Flask app as described in this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Gunicorn comes with the ability to [log](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#logging) and [reload](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.0/settings.html#reload) the application.

Apparently you cannot use gunicorn for debug mode as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13946679/5596800)

Comment: What about the debugger? Is there any option to see the debugger page?

Comment: @BurhanT. Edited the answer to include that.