# How to debug a Flask app which runs with gunicorn in a container?

Tags: python, linux, docker, flask, gunicorn

I have been looking for a way to start a python debugger so I can debug my flask app which is being executed with gunicorn inside a docker container and then connect to it with my VSCode from outside.

But I dont find any solutions. In fact someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950674/debugging-a-flask-app-running-in-gunicorn) suggests that it is not possible at all?

Is there a way to debug my flask app executed by gunicorn?

Comment: Can you debug your application in a simpler environment; for example, with the Flask dev server locally on your system, without Docker or GUnicorn; even if you're eventually going to deploy with those tools?

Comment: Locally no, but what I am trying now is to have a second debug container where I run the app just with the flask server and I ll use that for debbuging. I am trying that at the moment.

Comment: For debugging, I might not use a container at all.  Create a local virtual environment, install your application in it, and reproduce the issue there.

Comment: yeah no I want to use the container, for various reasons (well basically all the reasons that make containers usefull, not having to install locally anything, avoiding environment management locally, not having to reconfigure service to look to local machine for infra services which also run in containers etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like this is very difficult, if not impossible atm, to do with gunicorn. So what I did was

1. Create a `degub_app.py` file in my project with :

> ```
> from myapp.api import create_app
>
>
> if __name__=="__main__":
>     app = create_app()
>     app.run('0.0.0.0', 8000, debug=False)
> ```

2. I created a debug container which runs nothing on start it just waiting idle like this in my `docker-compose` file:

> ```
>  api-debug:
>         image: "myapp:latest"
>         restart: on-failure:3
>         environment:
>         volumes:
>           - ./:/usr/src/app
>         depends_on:
>           - rabbitmq
>           - redis
>           - mongo
>         tty: true
>         stdin_open: true
>         command: tail -F anything
>         ports:
>           - 8000:8000
> ```

3. Then using `VSCode` with the `Remote Container` pluggin i attached to that container. This starts a new VSCode window and shows you the files inside the container.

**Note** Since the VSCode is now connected to the container I had to re-install the Python extension (you can look this up but it is easy just go to pluggins and re-install to container)

4. I created a `launch.json` inside the container to run the `degub_app.py` that I mentioned above like this:

> {
> "version": "0.2.0",
> "configurations": [
> {
> "name": "Python: Debug API",
> "type": "python",
> "request": "launch",
> "program": "${workspaceFolder}my_path/debug_api.py",
> "console": "integratedTerminal",
> "justMyCode": false
> }
> ]
> }